# Deleted old linux images now ubuntu will not boot it just hangs

Tags: kernel

I know how to remove old linux images from Ubuntu but I think I screwed up deleting something I shouldn't have. What I did was:

`uname -r` and got `linux-image-3.13.0-35` (I did not remove this one.)

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image` (to get all the others I did not need)

I removed all the others including a `3.13.0-34` (i think I should have kept this.)

After I updated and it asked me to restart my computer and I did. I put in my HD password and it just stops after than. The Ubuntu screen dots that go from white to orange stop and it just hangs there. How do I fix this issue without wiping my HD? Is there a way to boot Ubuntu off a usb (my laptop doesn't have a cd drive) and just re-install over it without erasing my data?
I am running the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your GRUB is properly configured to use the right kernel as the default kernel?  You could check this out in the GRUB menu file under the /boot directory.  Sorry can't remember the exact name right now.

Also, you might consider re-installing the GRUB boot loader.

Final thought, hope you did not delete something else you should not have.  I'd suggest retrieving your /boot directory from backups, re-GRUBbing and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) is a guide on making an Ubuntu install USB stick.

If you made a separate partition for your home directory, then you can just re-install almost the same as you installed initially.
If you didn't, you could copy your home directory (/home/$USER) to a flash drive to back it up:

```
sudo tar -czf /media/USBSTICK/backup.tar.gz /home/$USER
```

To restore:

```
cd /home
sudo rm -rf ./$USER
tar -xzf /media/USBSTICK/backup.tar.gz
```

It is important to note that this won't back up any programs installed normally.